# Application crashed in iOS7 after reset Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

At the time of star coding in xcode 5, one thing that i struggle with is, with out any coding error or other reason my all applications got crash whenever i try to reset my "Simulator"!!! Not all the time, but most of the time it crashed. Some times it crashed at the time of quit. No matter with which version of simulator i using (iPhone Retina 3.5 Inch, iPhone Retina 4 Inch with iOS6 or iOS7). It always happen when a complete project (with no error, nothing) built on xcode 4.6 trying to quit after running in xcode 5. Though i keep the "Simulator version" as like in xcode 4.6.
If any one similar with this problem and have solution, please share it with me.
- Thanks a lot in advanced.

The error i am facing is : "Thread 1:signal SIGTERM"

Comment: How long are you working with iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you open your project with Xcode5 then all the settings for the views are changed to open with Xcode5, in order to make your project views to open with previous versions of xcode, you need to change the property of the views in file inspector to open with earlier versions default, by doing that your project would open in previous as well as current xcode version.

You could fix it in file inspector to open the views with the previous versions of Xcode if it is selected as Xcode5(**Default(5.0)**), by following image you could fix your views to open with the earlier versions of the xcode.

[image]

Comment: is this for firstViewController , which we set in appdelegate ?

Comment: it is for all of your views , it could be all xib or storyboard

Comment: so i have to change this for all views at the time of i create it if i am using xibs.

Comment: you will have to change for all the views, it is as simple as I write, for all the xibs

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your post @nsgulliver. My application is not crashing after unchecking the "Use Autolayout" option. Can you tell me for what reason i should tick that box? As far as i know this option should check at the time of using iOS 6 and upper version. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: If you were not using autoLayout in your project then it might start to work when you un-check the autolayout option in your xcode. but for using previous versions of xcode targeting earlier versions like iOS6, you need to change the xcode option as well.

Comment: Secondly AFAIK, autolayout in iOS7 are bit different than iOS6, although I have not tested myself autolayout in iOS7 yet.